# What concepts in pandas return a reference vs copy?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
D[D['Marks']>50]
```

This is filtering a data frame.

Does this return a *reference* to the original dataframe or a *copy*?

I think in **numpy** slicing returns reference where as filtering returns a copy.

How is this concept in pandas?

Answer (score 1):

its a ***copy*** as you see its diffrent id

[image]